# While doing angular i got error as follow

Tags: angular

Failed to compile.

src/app/app.module.ts:4:10 - error TS2305: Module '"./events-app.component"' has no exported member 'EventsAppComponent'.

4 import { EventsAppComponent } from './events-app.component';
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: How did you export your `EventsAppComponent` component? Can you share the code snippet of the component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module has no exported member error in angular module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234220/module-has-no-exported-member-error-in-angular-module)

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here
[Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234220/module-has-no-exported-member-error-in-angular-module)

Basically you will have to export your component class for it to be used.

`export class EventsAppComponent {}`

If this is not what you are looking for please add some more details to this question.